# pandas.DataFrame: How to div row by row [python]

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, division

I want to div `row[i]` by `row[i+1]` in `pandas.DataFrame`

```
row[i] = row[i+1] / row[i]
```

for example:

```
1 2 3 4

4 2 6 2

8 5 3 1
```

the result is

```
0.25 1 0.5 2

0.5 0.4 2 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can divide by [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)ed `DataFrame`, last remove `NaN` row by [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
print (df)
   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  3  4
1  4  2  6  2
2  8  5  3  1

print (df.div(df.shift(-1), axis=1))
      a    b    c    d
0  0.25  1.0  0.5  2.0
1  0.50  0.4  2.0  2.0
2   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

df = df.div(df.shift(-1), axis=1).dropna(how='all')
print (df)
      a    b    c    d
0  0.25  1.0  0.5  2.0
1  0.50  0.4  2.0  2.0
```

Another solution for remove last row is select by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = df.div(df.shift(-1), axis=1).iloc[:-1]
print (df)
      a    b    c    d
0  0.25  1.0  0.5  2.0
1  0.50  0.4  2.0  2.0
```